# brainstorm: dynamically block ports when not on VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall

I'm a remote developer working on a web application.  I'd like to share my work-in-progress to other users on the LAN (I'm on a VPN).  Other users should be able to find my web application using a browser at this URL:
http://x.x.x.x/myapp:8080.

If I open port 8080 on my laptop's firewall, the port will also be exposed when I'm off the VPN.  My employer doesn't want the port open to the public when I'm off the VPN.

Is there a way to dynamically allow 8080 while I"m on the VPN, and to automatically block 8080 when I'm not VPN (either logoff or connection broken)?  It would have to enable and disable the port depending on the VPN connection status.

Or, is there some other creative solution to grant network users access while blocking the public?  E.g. Allow IP clients with a certain subnet? Apache configuration?

Comment: Sadly, host configuration questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Open it to just your LAN and VPN IP subnet. This way it will only be accessible from other users on your internal networks, but not anyone else. (note, this isn't foolproof, but its a thought).

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. This question seems to be more related to server/computer configuration which is off topic as defined by the community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.